# LoadLibrary in IE addon does not work

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, dll, add-on

I have created a Stub DLL that works as an addon in IE. I want this stub dll in turn use LoadLibrary function to load another DLL and make a function call in it.

As long is this second DLL is registered inside IE as addon it works fine but if I donot register it as addon in IE my stub dll fails to load second dll.  If I register both dlls as addon in IE it works fine

Any suggestions how to handle this situation. I dont want to show two addons in the IE addon list.

Comment: Is the the DLL accessible via the load library search paths used by Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the directory that contains your stub dll is not in the search path for LoadLibrary(). We have done this in our application by determining the path of our stub dll, and then using that path to LoadLibrary() the full pathname of our extra dlls.

Comment: This worked for me. Probably I need to read more about LoadLibrary function. I thought, if dll is registered using regsvr32, LadLibrary would be able to pick it up automatically without requiring full path.